# Django. Default value from foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I use Django 1.9.1, Python 3.5. `models.py`:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Lot(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    count = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    price = models.FloatField(default = 1) #Price on the moment of buying
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.item.name

    def cost(self):
         return self.price * self.count
```

I want to create Lot object wiht default `price = item.price`. I.e. price on the moment of buying. So I can't obtain `price` value from Lot.item.price because it may be different. When code of `models.py` is like that:

```
class Lot(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    count = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    price = models.FloatField(default = item.price) #Price on the moment of buying
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.item.name

    def cost(self):
         return self.price * self.count
```

I get following error:

```
AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'price'
```

How should I correct this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `Lot.save` to set the default value for price.

```
class Lot(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    price = models.FloatField()
    ....

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.price:
            self.price = self.item.price
        super(Lot, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

`default` in your model definition is not 'instance-aware'. I'd suggest overriding the save method of `Lot` to pull in price at time of save.

```
class Lot(models.Model):

    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    count = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    price = models.FloatField(default = item.price) #Price on the moment of buying
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.item.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.item: # verify there's a FK
            self.price = self.item.price
        super(Lot, self).save(*args,**kwargs) # invoke the inherited save method; price will now be save if item is not null

    def cost(self):
         return self.price * self.count
```